# Python datetime range between start_date and end_date

Tags: python, django, datetime, calendar

I am trying to make a list of objects with a `date_and_time` attribute between a `start_date` and `end_date`

`start_date` and `end_date` are stored in a database and I call the database fields simple like this:

```
>>> data = Oncall.objects.all()
>>> data
[<Oncall: Oncall object>, <Oncall: Oncall object>, <Oncall: Oncall object>, <Oncall: Oncall object>]
```

I am trying to create a list with oncall objects for each date within the range as follows:

```
>>> event_list = []
>>> for i in range(1, calendar.monthrange(datetime.now().year, datetime.now().month)[1]):
...  for d in data:
...   if d.start_date <= datetime(year=datetime.now().year, month=datetime.now().month, day=i) <= d.end_date:
...    oncall=d
...    oncall.date_and_time=datetime(year=datetime.now().year, month=datetime.now().month, day=i)
...    event_list.append(oncall)
```

Unfortunately - I end up with this list:

```
>>> for i in event_list:
...  print str(i.user_id) + ' ' + str(i.date_and_time)
... 
amencke 2015-04-20 00:00:00
amencke 2015-04-20 00:00:00
amencke 2015-04-20 00:00:00
amencke 2015-04-20 00:00:00
amencke 2015-04-20 00:00:00
amencke 2015-04-20 00:00:00
amencke 2015-04-20 00:00:00
jbolggs 2015-04-27 00:00:00
jbolggs 2015-04-27 00:00:00
jbolggs 2015-04-27 00:00:00
jbolggs 2015-04-27 00:00:00
jbolggs 2015-04-27 00:00:00
jbolggs 2015-04-27 00:00:00
jbolggs 2015-04-27 00:00:00
jdoe 2015-04-29 00:00:00
jdoe 2015-04-29 00:00:00
```

Any ideas on how I could get the date to increment correctly?

Cheers, Arthur

Comment: use datetime.timedelta

Answer (score 0):

I might not have properly understood the question. If that is the case please comment and I will update the answer.

**Generate sample data:**

```
import datetime
import operator

mylist = []
# Demo class
class myclass:
    def __init__(self, name, date):
        self.name = name
        self.date = date

# List creation
names=["amencke", "amencke", "amencke", "amencke", "amencke", "amencke", "amencke", "jbolggs", "jbolggs", "jbolggs", "jbolggs", "jbolggs", "jbolggs", "jbolggs", "jdoe", "jdo"]
date=["2015-04-28 00:00:00", "2015-04-05 00:00:00", "2015-04-20 00:00:00", "2015-04-20 00:00:00", "2015-04-20 00:00:00", "2015-04-20 00:00:00", "2015-04-20 00:00:00", "2015-04-27 00:00:00", "2015-04-27 00:00:00", "2015-04-27 00:00:00", "2015-04-27 00:00:00", "2015-04-27 00:00:00", "2015-04-27 00:00:00", "2015-04-27 00:00:00", "2015-04-29 00:00:00", "2015-04-29 00:00:00"]        
#Create the list
for i in range(len(names)):
    mylist.append(myclass(names[i],datetime.datetime.strptime(date[i], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
```

**Sorting the list by date:**

```
sorted_mylist = sorted(mylist, key=operator.attrgetter('date'))
#print the original list
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    print mylist[i].name, mylist[i].date
#print the sorted list
for i in range(len(sorted_mylist)):
    print sorted_mylist[i].name, mylist[i].date
#sort and print the original list
mylist.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('date'))
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    print mylist[i].name, mylist[i].date
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems oncall is a pointer to the d objects.
You are effectively setting (and overwriting!) the matching d object's date_and_time to midnight on the i day:

```
oncall=d
oncall.date_and_time=datetime(year=datetime.now().year, month=datetime.now().month, day=i)
```

The list you print in the end contains multiple pointers to the same Oncall objects which have date_and_time set to the last i day for which the condition was met.

Something like this could be closer to what you expect (assuming I get your intention correctly):

```
date_and_time=datetime(year=datetime.now().year, month=datetime.now().month, day=i)
event_list.append((d, date_and_time))
```

followed by

```
for d, date_and_time in event_list:
    print str(d.user_id) + ' ' + str(date_and_time)
```

I'd also suggest computing year and month once instead of every loop iteration - would greatly improve your code's readability (and even speed a bit).

Comment: Hi Dan. Many thanks for your answer and explanation - I have just tried it and it works quite nicely - returning this data: `>>> event_list
[(<Oncall: Oncall object>, datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 14, 0, 0)), (<Oncall: Oncall object>, datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 15, 0, 0)), (<Oncall: Oncall object>, datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 16, 0, 0)), (<Oncall: Oncall object>, datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 17, 0, 0)), (<Oncall: Oncall object>, datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 18, 0, 0)),...` It may be slightly off for my current requirement but very useful nevertheless